# Menu JQuery não abre!

Tags: jquery, css, css3

A página é essa: http://www.magicforbaby.com.br/sobre.php

**Problema:** Quando estou em uma resolução menor que 800px (sim, estou fazendo uso de `media queries`), eu faço com que o menu se retraia em uma figura padrão, então, ao clicá-la, abre-se o menu. Mas esta dando erro:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined       sobre.php:69            
Uncaught ReferenceError: urlproduto is not defined   VM127:6
```

Sobre linha 69

```
  $(document).ready(function(e){

    $(".menuAbrir").click(function() {
      $(".menuNav").show();
      $(".menuAbrir").hide();
    });

    $(".menuFechar").click(function() {
      $(".menuNav").hide();
      $(".menuAbrir").show();
    });
  });
```

Tenho esse `JQuery` para abrir o menu como é incluído em todas as páginas. Mas nessa está dando esse erro;

Mais precisamente linha 69:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
```

**O que fazer?**

Comment: Talvez pode ser a ordem em que o <script src="jquery.js"> foi colocado, veja se ele está sendo referenciado antes desse script que voce postou.

Comment: Ex: <script src="jquery.js"> logo abaixo <script type="text/javascript"> ...seu codigo </script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olhando o codigo fonte da pagina não enconteri o link para o Jquery. Faça o seguinte:

Antes do seu código `<script type="text/javascript"> ...sua função </script>` adicione a referenci do seu arquivo jquery.js,  `<script src="jquery.js">`.

Comment: Desculpe, realmente esqueci de colocar. Cansaço faz isso! kkk. Aproveitando o ensejo, pode me explicar porque essa pagina, http://www.magicforbaby.com.br/contato.php?form, nos campos do formulário, localmente estão estilizados corretamente os inputs texts mas na web não estão estilizados corretamente sendo que os css estão corretamente postados?

Comment: Abra uma nova pergunta para o css, senão vai ficar muito comentario aqui

Comment: ok, vou fazer isso! Obrigado!

Comment: Se puder fechar a pergunta.

Comment: pode fechar sim